# Display all of the files where the extension starts with a certain letter using ls command

Tags: ls

How do I display all files where its extension start with a certain letter using ls command?

I tried doing `ls d*` but that display all files starting with letter d, not extension starting with letter d.

Comment: How about `ls *.d*`?

Comment: @AndyJ. You might eliminate some false positives by using the full extension or extensions. Can you give more details regarding exactly what you are looking to display?

Answer (score -1):

You will need to use asterisk.
Press "shift+8" to get it.
This "*" wildcard represents all the characters.
So, the code can be:

```
ls *.<your extension>
```

Example:

```
ls *.txt
```